# How to change wal_level to logical in postgresql database when configured via Helm charts

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, timescaledb, wal, logical-replication

I deployed timescale-postgresql using **helm**:

- **Chart Name**: `timescalepostgres timescale/timescaledb-single --version 0.33.1`

In the `values.yaml` file I kept the `wal_level = logical`, however after the deployment I see `wal_level` still showing the default value of `replica`.

How to change it?

During the **helm** chart deployment I explicitly mentioned the `wal_level:logical`, however it is not changing the default value of `replica`.

Answer (score 0):

If the values.yaml file's wal_level: logical setting isn't applied during deployment, make sure the YAML syntax is right, verify the compatibility of the Helm chart version, and use **--set** when installing or upgrading. If problems still arise, you might want to try setting up PostgreSQL directly with SQL **(ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = 'logical';)**.

Hope it works :)

Comment: I checked the YAML syntax in https://www.yamllint.com/...it shows valid
Apart from this I also tried to setting up PostgreSQL directly with SQL (ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = 'logical';).
it accepted the command however when i checked with the command : SHOW wal_level;
it again showed the default replica.

Comment: Regarding your another suggestion of  verify the compatibility of the Helm chart version, and use --set when installing or upgrading. Here you mean in the helm upgrade --install command I should set the wal_level=logical?
Kindly brief me abt this....thanks